# Controlling Finish action based on a condition

Tags: advanced-installer

I have an Advanced Installer(6.3) project, in the final Finish dialog, I have added an Finish Action to run an exe(this exe will be copied as a part of the installer). But I need this Finish Action to run only if a checkbox is checked? How do I add this condition in the Finish Action? Attaching a pic for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user's input on whether to run the application, you can attach a custom action to the Finish button instead (see http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-launch-application.html#section716)

> 1. make sure you are using at least an Enterprise or Architect project (you can  change the project type using the Project -> Options menu)
> 2. go to "Dialogs" page and select "ExitDialog"
> 3. select the Finish Actions tab
> 4. enable the "Launch application" option for the file you want to launch
> 5. make sure that the Checked by default option is set
> 6. select the "Launch Your Application" text control and set the "Visible" flag to "False" in its Properties pane
> 7. do the same for the checkbox control

You'll still need to launch the .exe from a custom action with the approriate condition.

If you want to allow the user to choose, but only if the condition is met, you could modify the above procedure by just having it control the visibility of the controls based on the condition (in order to do this you would need to modify the control conditions for the Checkbox control to hide when the condition is true, show when false instead of step #6).

Comment: Sorry for the late response @adamdc78, instead of choosing the Finish action, I now have the exe to be launched as a Custom Action in the Finish buttons Published Event. The problem now I'm facing is, the Installer dialog is waiting until the exe is closed instead of finishing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not quite clear on what's occurring; the dialog stays visible until the custom action finishes and then closes?

Comment: The Custom Action is an exe. On clicking finish in the dialog, the exe launches but the dialog does not close, if I close the exe, the dialog also closes.

Comment: Have you unchecked "Wait for custom action to finish before proceeding" in the custom action's `Execution Options`?